# Spring Roo Application File upload path

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

In my Spring Roo application I'm uploading some files on local server `VMware vFabric tc server` on `Spring source tool (STS)` platform. When user uploads some files via application it by default gets uploaded to STS IDE path (in my case `C:\Program Files\springsource\sts-2.8.1.RELEASE\tempDir)` but it should upload on server. I have the following code in my object to save the file:

```
    public void setFile(CommonsMultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;       
        this.size = file.getSize();

        int dotPos = tempFileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        String extension = file.getOriginalFilename().substring(dotPos + 1);
            this.fileName = new Date().getTime() + "." + extension; 

        File outputFile = new File(pathToSave + fileName);
        if (outputFile == null || !outputFile.exists()) {
            new File(pathToSave).mkdirs();
        }
        try {
            file.transferTo(outputFile);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How can I upload files to server instead of IDE path?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat can be configured to use any directory (that it has write access to) for file uploads (see [Configure Tomcat to use a different temp directory for file uploads](https://serverfault.com/questions/13523/configure-tomcat-to-use-a-different-temp-directory-for-file-uploads) on serverfault).

Since `VMware vFabric tc server` comes bundled with STS it is probably pre-configured to use the temp directory of the IDE. This technically still ***is*** on the server because you're running on `localhost`